# Multiple MySQL queries (no PHP)

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to perform a SQL query then update another table with the generated ID and continue through all of the rows?

I have this SQL query that works but what I need to do is after each row is added to cards to then update merged.cars_id with the last generated ID so they are linked. normally I would do this with PHP but ideally I would like to just do it with MySQL if possible.

MAIN QUERY

```
INSERT INTO cards (first_contact_date, card_type, property_id, user_id)
SELECT first_contact_date, 'P', property_id, user_id FROM merged
```

THEN I NEED WITH MATCHING ROWS (Roughly)

```
 UPDATE merged SET merged.card_id = LAST_INSERT_ID (FROM ABOVE) into the matching record..
```

Is something like this possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using MySQL triggers to do this
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

A trigger is a function that will be executed AFTER or BEFORE the INSERT or DELETE or UPDATE is done over any record of your table.

In your case you need to do a AFTER INSERT on **cards** that just updates the **merged** table. Make sure its AFTER insert as you wont be able to access the new row's ID otherwise.

The code would look something like this, assuming the id field from the cards table its named "id"

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER updating_merged AFTER INSERT ON cards
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE merged SET card_id = NEW.id;
  END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just trying to workout how to write this. I have this at the moment but where do I put the original insert SQL line:

CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_cards`  
    AFTER INSERT ON `cards` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO merged (card_id) VALUES (NEW.card_id);  
    END

Comment: A trigger is a function that will always be triggered when you insert (in this case) a new row on that table, the trigger is kind of part of the schema of the table, so once you create it you dont need to worry ever again about it, just keep inserting rows and the trigger funcion will be called every time by MySQL.

Comment: OK thanks, I have worked out how to setup a trigger now in my SQL program (HeidiSQL) however when I run my original insert I get an error of:

Can't update table 'merged' in trigger because it is used by statement which involked this stored trigger..?

Thanks

Comment: The issue its as the error states, in your statement you have a select over the merged table so you cant use that table for the trigger. You have a few work arounds, if you are using pure MySQL then use a variable to store the contents of the merged query and then use that variable to do the insert over the cards table. If you are using code like PHP just separate the insert from the select into two different queries.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest Stored Procedures?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

**--EDIT--**

Ah yes, triggers.  For this particular situation, Jimmy has the answer.  I will leave this post for the sake of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a trigger to do this.  For mysql, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html.  This is what triggers are designed to handle.